# Sufficient condition for weak existence of SDE's solutions.

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

It's a well known result due to Skorokhod that if for the SDE:
$$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
the coefficients $b(t,x)$ and $\sigma(t,x)$ are assumed to be *continuous* and *bounded* then weak existence holds.

On Ikeda & Watanabe's book (in particular theorem IV.2.3.) the authors state:

> Given continuous coefficients $\sigma(x)$ and $b(x)$ of the (time
>   homogeneous) markovian type SDE
>
> $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t$$  Then for any probability measure
>   $\mu$ with compact support there exists a solution for the SDE whose
>   initial distribution coincides with $\mu$.

(Worthy is to notice that the resulting solution may be explosive, but nonetheless this could be "solved" by assuming square integrability of the intial condition and linear growth.)

I am searching for further references regarding this particular result (which seems to be not so well-known). Neither Karatzas & Shreve nor Revuz & Yor seem to mention it.  In the survey by Cherny and Engelbert they just mention the classic result due to Skorokhod and the same happens in Strook & Varadhan.

That's why I am curious about this result mentioned by Ikeda & Watanabe, which is less restrictive (even though it seems to apply just to the time homogeneous Markovian case).

Thanks in advance for any comment!

Comment: Do the authors provide a proof? Since they start with a compactly supported distribution, it's possible you could take a sequence of compactly supported continuous functions $\{\varphi_N\}$, with $\varphi_N=1$ on $[-N,N]$, apply the classical result for the coefficients $(b\varphi_N,\sigma\varphi_N)$, then show the corresponding solutions converge in an appropriate sense as $N\to\infty$. I haven't checked the details, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jason . If I'm honest with you I didn't understand their proof even though I've gone through it  many times. Tomorrow I'll add some extra details and maybe I could manage to understand it with your help

Comment: You mean something like a mollified indicator function?

Comment: If I get time, I'll see if I have access to an online copy of the text and have a look myself.